# How to derive the formula for the radius of a Fermi sphere?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

I'm trying to figure out how the radius of a Fermi sphere
$$p_F = \hbar (3 \pi^2 \frac{N}{V})^{1/3}$$
is derived from the formula 
$$dN_{spatial}=\frac{V \ d^3p}{\hbar^3}.$$
The solution states that I should arrive at the following
$$\frac{2V}{(2 \pi \hbar)^3} \cdot \frac{4\pi}{3}p_F^3.$$
However I am not quite sure how I should go about after the following
$$2\int dN_{spatial} = \frac{2V}{\hbar^3}\int d^3p= \ ?$$
I would love some help to solve this, and if you have any web resources I'd gladly accept that too (I've tried googling my way for a while now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be $h$ in the denominator of your second equation,

$$
{\rm d}N = \frac{V}{h^3}{\rm d}^3{\bf p}
$$

Integrating at both sides, and taking into account the degeneracy

$$
N = \frac{2 V}{h^3} \int{\rm d}^3 {\bf p} = \frac{2 V}{h^3} \int {\rm d}\Omega\int_0^{p_F}{\rm d}p ~p^2 = \frac{2V}{h^3} \frac{4\pi}{3} p_F^3 
$$

Using $2\pi\hbar = h$ you get

$$
N = \frac{2V}{(2\pi \hbar)^3} \frac{4\pi}{3}p_F^3
$$

and from here is just a matter of getting $p_F$

$$
p_F = \hbar \left(3\pi^2 \frac{N}{V} \right)^{1/3} = \hbar k_F
$$

Comment: You are correct, seems like a typo in the exercise. However could you explain the part of $\int d\Omega$ with degeneracy?

Comment: That's the integral of the solid angle $d \Omega = \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$

Comment: @PhyCoMath It is just a short version of the integration over the angle . $\int {\rm d}\Omega = \int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi \int_0^{\pi}{\rm d}\theta\sin \theta$

Comment: @caverac Oh, never seen that notation before. Thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: @PhyCoMath :) Happy to help